# Problems compiling iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, armv7

I have problems compiling my project in XCODE 5

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myuser/Projects/myProject/Security.framework/Security, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/myuser/Projects/myProject/Security.framework/Security (2 slices)

Comment: It looks like the binary at `/Users/myuser/Projects/myProject/Security.framework/Security` doesn't contain a armv7 slice. You can confirm this by running `lipo -info /Users/myuser/Projects/myProject/Security.framework/Security`. If it doesn't have the armv7 slice, you'll need a version of that framework that does have it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is evident from the message, your Security.framework seems to have files missing for arm7 architecture. You can try to either reinstall XCode or simply replace Security.framework from some other working system.
Location of Framework files :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```